# Join to a voice channel where the member is connected

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want my bot to join the channel where the member is. I tried with some code, but none of them are worked.

```js
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if (newMember.tag = "Dummy#0001") {
        newMember.voice.join();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `voiceStateUpdate` event in discord.js v12 emits `oldState` and `newState` representing the `VoiceState`s of the member instead of the member itself. As the [`VoiceState`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState) doesn't have a `tag` property, your if statement won't work (also because of the single `=`).

A `VoiceState` has a [`member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=member) property, it's the member that this voice state belongs to. You can grab the member's `user` property's `tag`. The `VoiceState` also has a [`channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=channel) property, it's the `VoiceChannel` that the member is connected to. Voice channels have a [`join()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=join) method you can use to join the channel.

The following should work as expected:

```js
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
  if (newState.member.user.tag !== 'Dummy#0001') return;
  if (!newState.channel) return;

  newState.channel
    .join()
    .then((connection) => console.log('Connected!'))
    .catch(console.error);
});
```